# Does thread-safe mean no race conditions?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition, thread-synchronization

ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe, but race conditions can occur, because as I understand only parts of the map are locked and only for write operations meaning that if there is a read operation at the same time there will be a race condition.

But I read also like here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

```
Thread safe: Implementation is guaranteed to be free of race conditions when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.
```

Can I say that ConcurrentHashMap is thread-safe, but not fully synchronized? What is the right terminology here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know that there is a formal definition of "thread safe."

When people say that some *class* is thread safe, they usually mean that concurrent use of the class methods by several threads can not cause behavior that would surprise a reasonable programmer who has read the class documentation.

"Thread safe" for a `Map` would mean things like:

- If two or more threads store different keys, all of the stores will happen.
- If two or more threads store different values for the same key, at least one of the stores will happen.
- If one thread stores a value for a key while another thread attempts to get the value for that key, then the reading thread will either get the old value or the new value.
- The value for key K will never change because of multiple threads accessing and/or storing other keys.
- Concurrent use of the same map by multiple threads will never cause the JVM to throw a `VirtualMachineError`, or cause it to segfault.
- etc.

Note that some of the above are examples of race conditions that the class itself is powerless to prevent. "Thread safe" is *not* a promise that your program will be free from race conditions if you use a thread safe class. It only promises that the class's own source code will not be the cause of thread-related bugs in your program.

Comment: @curiousguy, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/VirtualMachineError.html If it happens, then the most likely causes would be a bug in the JVM implementation, or some bad thing that happened inside a native method. I doubt that there are many `Map` implementations that use native methods, so maybe that particular example is a bit far-fetched.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

"Thread-safe" might depend on subjective interpretation, while "race condition" is more objective and abstract.

### Explanation:

For example, in C++ `cout` "as such" is thread-safe at its own implementation level. You won't see your app crashing or outputting garbled symbols to the single console (shared resource) when calling `cout` from multiple threads in parallel.

However, if you use `cout` to output your text strings from parallel threads, at one point you will see your text messed up at character sequence level because there is undoubtedly a race condition going on.

Does it mean `cout` is not thread-safe? I lean towards "no" because C++ standard says it is thread-safe enough (I'll return to that later).

Does it mean your code is not thread-safe? It depends on the situation.

If outputting intermixed text fragments is what you and users of your code expected, then the code can be considered thread-safe from the user's perspective, despite the fact that it has a race condition (accessing shared resource - console - without synchronizing).

But if someone complains and you have to rewrite your code, then it means it was not considered thread-safe enough.

So, "not thread-safe" might be loosely defined as "causing undesired behavior because of race conditions".

If there is no undesired behavior because of race conditions, then it might depend on subjective interpretations. I would say the code might still be considered thread-safe from the user's perspective, although technically it is not because it ignores the race conditions.

Returning to the console output topic. In .NET, it seems Microsoft thought that console output from C++ is not thread-safe enough (so again - subjective interpretation), so they implemented it differently and you can output entire strings to `Console.Write` without mixing texts from different threads.

Quoting Microsoft about their .NET console:

> I/O operations that use these streams are synchronized, which means
> that multiple threads can read from, or write to, the streams.

And quoting C++ standard:

> Concurrent access to a synchronized (§27.5.3.4) standard iostream
> object’s formatted and unformatted input (§27.7.2.1) and output
> (§27.7.3.1) functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall
> not result in a data race (§1.10). [ Note: Users must still
> synchronize concurrent use of these objects and streams by multiple
> threads if they wish to avoid interleaved characters. ]

So, C++ considered `cout` to be thread-safe enough, even despite the fact it had a logical race condition that could lead to interleaved characters. Microsoft, in contrast, felt that it is not thread-safe enough for their purposes, and added protection against this race condition.

So that is why I consider "thread-safe" to be subjective and context-dependent, while race condition is something that can be more objectively pinpointed to decide if you want to deal with it or not.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes thread-safe means there is no possibility of data races.

Because thread-safety means: "A data type or static method is thread-safe if it *behaves correctly when used from multiple threads, regardless of how those threads are executed*, and without demanding additional coordination from the calling code." ([MIT, course on Software Construction](https://web.mit.edu/6.031/www/fa17/classes/20-thread-safety/))

Race conditions are basically what is said to not happen in thread-safe code: "A race condition is a flaw that *occurs when the timing or ordering of events affects a program’s correctness*". ([John Regehr, University of Utah](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/490))

Answer (score 0):

Race condition happens when an entity is updated or modified, by multiple accessors simultaneously. For mere reading, there is no race condition because a read is not the same as update or modification.

---

ConcurrentHashMap being thread-safe means that the aspects of this DS where race condition can occur, have been taken care of.

Therefore... Yes, even though not all methods in ConcurrentHashMap are protected from concurrent access, ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe because for those methods concurrent access is a non-issue.

Comment: @curiousguy: Says what?

Comment: Who defined: "Race condition happens with resources that are non-shareable"?

Answer (score 0):

> but race conditions can occur, because (snip)

Because any non trivial use of any "thread safe" primitive, even a mutex, **involves a race, *by definition***.

**If there was no race** to access a resource, you wouldn't even be concerned with "thread safety", as **accesses would be sequential**.

Comment: @curiosa Race condition would imply that different runs of the same algorithm don't see the same value of variables. Think a counter on page views on a very simple MT HTTP server. Each thread could randomly be assigned new HTTP TCP connections, and worker threads could be assigned HTTP GET requests. Each would update stat counters and cook a webpage with many elements. The HTTP user only cares about the page and the admin cares that the total counters are correct.

Comment: @curiosa When is a race not a race condition?

Comment: That's what I wanted to point out. The narrow technical meaning of it as laid out e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) is actually better captured by the synonymous term "race hazard". When a race is not hazardous, there will be no race hazard, and no race condition (in the technical sense). Still there will be a race. I do agree, that the term isn't that catchy really.

Comment: @curiosa "_where the system's substantive behavior_" Seeing a value of 1 or 2 in an integer is as substantive as it gets when dealing with integer. This is what racing for a hits counter will do. At the end of the day, it doesn't change the result. We still have a non determinism in the program execution: **two executions won't produce the same trace**.

Comment: Ah, that's a good one. So only stateless functions pose no hazard, and a Map is anything but stateless. Unless you come up with synchronization, taking out the hazard, thus taking out the race condition. Or with something else like they did with [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

Comment: @curiosa Any case where traces diverge at some point is inherently a hazard as nothing tells you *a priori* that they will end up with equivalent results.

Comment: I just had a look at the ConcurrentHashMap implementation, there are quite some 'synchronized' keywords and lots of 'volatile' modifiers. Hope there's no hazard, and no randomly diverging traces.

Comment: @curiosa Obviously the class itself needs either synchronized, volatile or other data race safe primitives. But the hazard doesn't have to come from the "thread safe" class. **It's the job of the user code to not be dependent on which concurrent operation is done first.**